# How to add the items in subset in c & store them in some array or some datatype so I can access each sum for further comparison?

Tags: c, set, subset

I have generated subset of a set I want to calculate the sum of that set like the output is:

```
Enter the elements of main set :3
1
2
There are 8 subsets
Subset 7 = 3 1 2
Subset 6 = 1 2
Subset 5 = 3 2
Subset 4 = 2
Subset 3 = 3 1
Subset 2 = 1
Subset 1 = 3
Subset 0 =
```

Here from the output, I want to calculate sum  1+2+3,1+2,3+2,...same for all subset, but sum should be in that way I can access each of the sums for further comparison how should I do that?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_subset(int subset, int *set) {
    int pos=0;
    printf("Subset %d = ", subset);
    while (subset) {
        if (subset & 1) {
            printf("%d ", set[pos]);
        }
        subset >>= 1;
        pos++;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    int no_of_element=3;
    int no_of_subset,x,a[50];

    printf("Enter the elements of main set :");
    for(x=0;x<no_of_element;x++)
        scanf("%d",&a[x]);

    no_of_subset= (1 << no_of_element);
    printf("There are %d subsets\n", no_of_subset);

    for (; no_of_subset--;) {
        print_subset(no_of_subset, a);
    }
}
```

Comment: In `print_subset`, when you are printing each number, also add it to a sum (that was initialized to zero). After printing all the numbers in a subset, print the sum. Or, if you want to calculate the sum in a routine other than `print_subset`, copy the code from `print_subset` to figure out the elements in the subset but omit the printing part.

Comment: Hey thanks for prompt response could you edit the code & let me know i m still not getting you.

Comment: @ROCKY have you thought about duplicates? example: 3 elements {2,2,2} gives duplicated sets (2,2) (2,2) ....

Comment: @Landstalker Its ok if there are duplicates could you please help me in this code how to get sum for each subset generated ?

Comment: @EricPostpischil awaiting your response

Comment: @Landstalker  ty very much how can i access each sum if i want to access sum =6,sum=4,sum=3  etc for comparisson then? –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here your code with sum:

```
void print_subset(int subset, int *set) {
    int pos=0;
    int sum=0;
    printf("Subset %d = ", subset);
    while (subset) {
        if (subset & 1) {
            printf("%d ", set[pos]);
            sum+=set[pos];
        }
        subset >>= 1;
        pos++;
    }
    printf("==> Sum = %d \n", sum);
}

int main() {
    int no_of_element=3;
    int no_of_subset,x,a[50];

    printf("Enter the elements of main set :");
    for(x=0;x<no_of_element;x++)
        scanf("%d",&a[x]);

    no_of_subset= (1 << no_of_element);
    printf("There are %d subsets\n", no_of_subset);

    for (; no_of_subset--;) {
        print_subset(no_of_subset, a);
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: If you use right shift, dont use signed integers - it is implementation specific what the compiler does if the sign bit is set - in your implementation, and the compiler handles it by performing sign extension your while loop will never terminate...

Comment: @Landstalker ty very much how can i access each sum if i want to access 6,4,3 for comparisson then?